# Image transitioning jquery

Tags: jquery, image

At the moment I'm developing a site and this is my first project using jquery. I'm using jquery to handle the calling of the images, but at the moment I'm not really liking how it is handling the transition from one image to another, the previous image which is about to be replaced is moved shifted due to the change of width to the image container and then replaced. I was wondering if there is a better way in which this can be handled as so far I have tried using the ready method to guarantee the new image is completely loaded before width of the container is changed, but it does nothing.

the link to my site is below

http://www.neuromanga.com/mangaReader1.0.php?cid=1

Comment: Please post the pertinent code. - Also I'd probably dynamically add a hash to the url of each page so as to be able to bookmark each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **load** instead of **ready** to determine if the image is loaded.
**ready** indicates that the document-tree has been loaded.

Comment: Thanks that completely fixed the problem